# inflate uv's. is it possible?

Tags: uv

Is it possible to 'inflate' the uv islands, something similar to Alt+S Shrink/Fatten in the 3D view?
Couldn't find an answer searching through the built-in add-ons, but is there any add-on out there that could do that?

I'd like the uv's to spread/inflate, so it can cover more texture space.
[image]

Many thanks

Comment: Did you try scaling with proportional editing?

Comment: @joshsanfelici Ha! That's actually a good solution but still it is 'local'. I'm looking for the whole uv to inflate as one similar to the alt+s

Comment: Yoy can do it by enlarging the area of influence of proportinal editing (scroll wheel), or maybe I didn't understand what you need.

Comment: @joshsanfelici, it's not the same, try alt+s on a 3d model vs proportional editing

Comment: Hello :). Shrink/Fatten uses face normals, so it wouldn't work in 2D. What's your desired result, could you please add some images?

Comment: @JachymMichal, well I've got this vein that I want the uv's to spread, so it can cover more texture space.
https://ibb.co/BzcdpDL